# Angular promise not resolving in jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, promise, q

I have the following jasmine test:

```
it('should resolve promise', inject(function ($q, $rootScope) {

    function getPromise(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        setTimeout(function(){
            deferred.resolve(true);
        }, 1000);
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    var p = getPromise();
    var cb = jasmine.createSpy();

    runs(function(){
        expect(cb).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

        p.then(cb);

        $rootScope.$apply();
    });

    waitsFor(function(){
        return cb.callCount == 1;
    });

    runs(function(){
        expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalled();

        $rootScope.$apply();
    });

}));
```

I thought $rootScope.$apply was supposed to resolve all outstanding promises, but somehow it does not happen in this test.

How do i trigger promise resolving in a test like this? please help!

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using? With angularJS 1.2, promises are A+ compliant and they _should_ resolve without an explicit call to execute the `$digest` loop.

Comment: i am using angular 1.2. Well i know they SHOULD resolve in the digest loop. But, they don't. :-(

Comment: Well, when i call $apply directly after resolve, it works. But i think  this is still strange behavior. When i try to use the same solution in my real unit test (the one presented here is just for testing the $apply behavior) it fails. So, it seems i still have a problem!

Comment: Did only `$scope.$apply` work and not `$timeout`? I'll remove it from the solution if it didn't.

Comment: i prepared a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/mKRgNQYqJkccbPgzPEBe

The apply method does work, the timeout solution doesn't. wich is weird

Comment: That rung a bell. The `$timeout` service is mocked by `ngMock` (Doh!) and one explicitly needs to call `$timeout.flush()`: http://plnkr.co/edit/Bdh78ZiArbO8vau9ByVJ?p=preview

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the `$rootScope.$apply()` is being called too soon in your case. This should work:

```js
function getPromise(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    setTimeout(function(){
        deferred.resolve(true);
        $rootScope.$apply();
    }, 1000);
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

**Update**

You can inject [mock `$timeout` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24timeout) and resolve the promise in that explicitly using `$timeout.flush()`.

```js
it('should resolve promise', inject(function ($q, $timeout, $rootScope) {

    function getPromise(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function(){
            deferred.resolve(true);
        }, 1000); 
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    // ...

    $timeout.flush();

    // ...
```