# Testing AngularJS promises in Jasmine 2.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I've been trying to wrap my head around Jasmine 2.0 and AngularJS promises. I know that:

- [Jasmine 2.0 introduced the `done` function](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) to replace the old `runs` and `waitsFor` functions
- [AngularJS `$q` promises will not resolve until a digest cycle is triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20311552/2892649)

How can I test AngularJS promises using the new async syntax in Jasmine 2.0?

Comment: If testing promises, why do you need to use the async syntax at all, both in old and new Jasmine? Can you post a function that you're trying to test? For a lot of cases, you can use `$timeout.flush()`, and/or `myPromise.resolve()` in tests to force them to be synchronous.

Comment: @MichalCharemza To my surprise, `$timeout.flush()` works great without the use of Jasmine's `done`; I don't have a function to demonstrate when I would need `done` + `$timeout.flush()`. What if the tests use e.g. an actual `$http` backend? It's (obviously) better to mock `$http` for speed, but would `$timeout.flush()` without `done` work there? Does the delayed resolution of the promise make any difference?

Comment: If the tests use an actual `$http` backend, connecting to a real server, then the test would be asynchronous, and you have to use `done`. `$timeout.flush()` (or `$httpBackend.flush()`) affects the code running locally: you can't call a function to demand that a server respond to the request right now! If you're not sure about how to test a specific function (say, using `$timeout` or `$http`), then you can post that function in a question).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

After your call to `promise.resolve()`:

- Call [`$timeout.flush()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$timeout). This will force a digest cycle and propagate the promise resolution
- Call `done()`. This tells Jasmine the async tests have completed

Here's an example ([**Demo on Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MITMRE?p=preview)):

```
describe('AngularJS promises and Jasmine 2.0', function() {
    var $q, $timeout;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$q_, _$timeout_) {
        // Set `$q` and `$timeout` before tests run
        $q = _$q_;
        $timeout = _$timeout_;
    }));

    // Putting `done` as argument allows async testing
    it('Demonstrates asynchronous testing', function(done) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function() {
            deferred.resolve('I told you I would come!');
        }, 1000); // This won't actually wait for 1 second.
                  // `$timeout.flush()` will force it to execute.

        deferred.promise.then(function(value) {
            // Tests set within `then` function of promise
            expect(value).toBe('I told you I would come!');
        })
        // IMPORTANT: `done` must be called after promise is resolved
        .finally(done);

        $timeout.flush(); // Force digest cycle to resolve promises
    });
});
```

Comment: Just wanted to add a link to K. Scott Allen's post on the beforeEach inject technique that you are using here: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/15/a-few-thoughts-on-better-unit-tests-for-angularjs-controllers.aspx

Comment: upvoted, seriously, only adding $timeout.flush() fixes my specs. really too bad this is not that well documented...

Comment: done is not needed above, all job is done by $timeout.flush()

Comment: Is there any reason to use `$timeout.flush()` instead of `$rootScope.apply()`? That is what the official documentation uses: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#testing

Comment: According to [Pawel Kozlowski's reply on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10340#issuecomment-65791569), using `$timeout.$flush()` will also clear timers. Most of the time `$rootScope.$apply()` works perfectly, but `$timeout.$flush()` covers more use cases

Answer (score 4):

For me the `$timeout.flush()` didn't work very well, but I've multiple async calls in my spec. I found the `$rootScope.$apply()`, as a method to force the `digest`on each async call.

```
describe('AngularJS promises and Jasmine 2.0', function () {
  beforeEach(inject(function (_$q_, _$timeout_, _$rootScope_) {
    $q = _$q_
    $timeout = _$timeout_
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_
  }))

  it('demonstrates asynchronous testing', function (done) {
    var defer = $q.defer()

    Async.call()
    .then(function (response) {
      // Do something

      var d = $q.defer()
      Async.call()
      .then(function (response) {
        d.resolve(response)
        $rootScope.$apply() // Call the first digest 
      })
      return d.promise
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      // Do something after the first digest

      Async.call()
      .then(function (response) {
        defer.resolve(response) // The original defer
        $rootScope.$apply() // Call the second digest
      })
    })

    defer.promise.then(function(value) {
      // Do something after the second digest
      expect(value).toBe('I told you I would come!')
    })
    .finally(done)

    if($timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks())
      $timeout.flush() 
  })
})
```

It is like a chained async calls thing. Hope it helps the conversation. 
Regards

Answer (score 4):

This answer won't add anything new to those of above, it is only intended to articulate the answer in more detailed way, as it worked for me. When I occurred the issue described in a question above, I spent much time tryng to find a way to make sure all promises had their time to finish and all assertions were asserted.

In my case I had a chain of promises, and after each of them I need to ensure the results do match my expectation. I did not create any promise using `deferred`, I rather invoked the existing ones.

So, the thing is that `$timeout.flush()` was completely enough for me. My working test looks like this:

```
describe("Plain command without side-effects", function() {
    it("All usecases", inject(function($timeout) {
        console.log("All together");
        expect(state.number).toEqual(1);
        cmdHistory
            .execute(increaseState, decreaseState)
            .then(function() {
                console.log("Execute works");
                expect(state.number).toEqual(2);
                return cmdHistory.redo(); // can't redo, nothing's undone
            })
            .then(function() {
                console.log("Redo would not work");
                expect(state.number).toEqual(2);
                return cmdHistory.undo();
            })
            .then(function() {
                console.log("Undo undoes");
                expect(state.number).toEqual(1);
                return cmdHistory.undo();
            })
            .then(function() {
                console.log("Next undo does nothing");
                expect(state.number).toEqual(1);
                return cmdHistory.redo(); // but still able to redo

            })
            .then(function() {
                console.log("And redo redoes neatly");
                expect(state.number).toEqual(2);
            });

        $timeout.flush();
    }));
```

This test is dedicated to make sure that commandHistory object works fine, it has to actions: `execute` and `unExecute`, and three methods: `execute`, `undo`, `redo`, all of which return promises.

Without `$timeout.flush()`, all I had in log output was `All together`, and no further log messages. Adding `$timeout.flush()` has fixed everything up, and now I have all messages shown and all assertions executed

**UPDATE**
There's another option: you can write your test suite without chaining promises with `then`, but simply flushing after each promise has been called, so that to make sure it completes:

```
    it("All usecases 2", inject(function($timeout) {
        console.log("All usecases 2");
        expect(state.number).toEqual(1);

        console.log("Execute works");
        cmdHistory.execute(increaseState, decreaseState);
        $timeout.flush();
        expect(state.number).toEqual(2);

        console.log("Redo would not work");
        cmdHistory.redo(); // can't redo, nothing's undone
        $timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks();
        expect(state.number).toEqual(2);

        console.log("Undo undoes");
        cmdHistory.undo();
        $timeout.flush();
        expect(state.number).toEqual(1);

        console.log("Next undo does nothing");
        cmdHistory.undo();
        $timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks();
        expect(state.number).toEqual(1);

        console.log("And redo redoes neatly");
        cmdHistory.redo(); // but still able to redo
        $timeout.flush();
        expect(state.number).toEqual(2);
    }));
```

Please pay attention to the fact in some cases, when my methods like `undo` and `redo` do not return promise, I call `$timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks()` instead of `flush`. Which is hard to say if it's good or bad.

Yet in this case test looks more reasonable and much simpler.