# Testing AngularJS Services using $q within Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, promise, indexeddb

Angulars build in `$q` promise implementation makes it hard for me to create tests in my Jasmine testing environment. I build a simple service which only purpose is to open an IndexedDB database:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service('idb', function ($q) {
    var dbName = 'TestDb';

    this.open = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var request = indexedDB.open(dbName, 1);

        request.onsuccess = function () {
            deferred.resolve();
        };
        request.onerror = function () {
            deferred.reject();
        }; 

        return deferred.promise;
    };
});
```

Here is my test in **Jasmine**:

```
describe('indexed db test', function () {
    var idbOpened = false;
    var idb, $rootScope;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_idb_, _$rootScope_) {
        idb = _idb_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    beforeEach(function (done) {
        idb.open().then(

        function () {
            idbOpened = true;
        },

        function () {
            idbOpened = false;
        })['finally'](done);

        $rootScope.$digest();
    });

    it('checks if indexeddb is opened', function () {
        expect(idbOpened).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

You can find [a jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dasboe/Vf4wG/)

The test fails with a timeout because the asynchronous callback for finally is not invoked.

I understand I have to call `$rootScope.$digest()` after the promise is resolved because Angular puts the `promise.resolve` callbacks on the `evalAsync` queue.

What I don't understand is how I can do this in my Testing environment. Obviously how I'm calling it is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29155447/2599875, and basically what works for me was the method `$rootScope.$apply()` at the end of the callback of `each async call`.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code like so, and it worked

//--- CODE --------------------------

```
(function (angular) {
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.service('idb', function ($q, $rootScope) {
        var dbName = 'TestDb';

        this.open = function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var request = indexedDB.open(dbName, 1);

            request.onsuccess = function () {
                console.log("db opened");
                deferred.resolve();
                $rootScope.$digest();
            };
            request.onerror = function () {
                deferred.reject();
            };

            return deferred.promise;
        };
    });
})(angular);
```

// --- SPECS -------------------------

```
describe('indexed db test', function () {
    var idbOpened = false;
    var idb, $rootScope;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_idb_, _$rootScope_) {
        idb = _idb_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    beforeEach(function (done) {
        idb.open().then(

        function () {
            idbOpened = true;
        },

        function () {
            idbOpened = false;
        })['finally'](done);

        $rootScope.$digest();
    });

    it('checks if indexeddb is opened', function () {
        expect(idbOpened).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```