# Jasmine support for testing method logic that runs after a returned promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, jasmine

I have a java script method I want to test.  It looks something like this (this is simplified psudocode, forgive typos)

```
$scope.savePerson = function(){
      Person.create($scope.person).then(function(newPerson){
          if($scope.person.org){
             Organization.addPerson($scope.person.org, newPerson.id);
          }

     toaster.pop('success', "person added");
}
```

This is using restangular, but the idea is simple.  When the savePerson method is called it first saves the person object, once that save completes it then tries to save the person to an organization *if* organization is set.  The org can't be saved until person has been.

I want to test this logic by creating spys for person and organization and then expecting that they are both called.  A naive approach may look something like this:

```
describe( 'save person', function () {
var Person, Organization, person;


beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $q, _Organization_, _Person_) {
   Person=_Person_;
   Organization=_Organization_;
   person={...} //whaver goes here, but include an org

   Person.create=jasmine.createSpy('create()').andCallFake( funciton(newPerson){
       var defer = $q.defer();
       defer.resolve(personParam);
       return defer.promise;
  });

  Organization.addPerson= jasmine.createSpy('addPerson()').andCallFake(funciton(personParam){
     var defer=$q.defer();
     defer.resolve(personParam);
     return defer.promise;
  });

 controllerOptions.Person=Person;
 controllerOptions.Organization=Organization;
 controllerOptions.person=person;
 MyController= $controller('MyController', controllerOptions);
}));

it('adds org if exists', function(){
   $scope.savePerson($scope.person);

  expect(Person.create).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(Organization.addPerson).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

This will fail as written, specifically addPerson will not be called.  This isn't a flaw in the code, it's an issue with threading.  Because my code calls .then on person.create it's creating an async thread to run in.  Organization.addPerson will not be called until the async thread kicks in and the then logic is run.  The problem is that my test continues running without waiting for that thread, and so it gets to the expect calls and fails.

Now a very lazy fix would be to add a short 10 millisecond wait in my test.  The moment that this test waits the async thread will kick in, get a response immediately, and call addPerson.  However, this is relaying on presumptions on how interrupts will occur, and is not rigorous enough for testing.

I believe I could also address this by having my origination.addPerson function set some "addPersonCalled" value and then using [async calls](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/test-asynchronous-methods-using-the-jasmine-runs-and-waitfor-methods.html#fbid=dwgZTfTa9Cz) that runs only once the addPersonCalled method is set, but it looks a little ugly.

This seems like a common use case.  I was wondering if jasmine had a cleaner method of supporting this use case?  Is there some way to tell jasmine to wait for any current .then methods called on your promise to resolve before continuing a test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two options available for us.  The first is to call either $timeout.flush() or $rootScope.$apply() which will resolve all promises ([Testing AngularJS promises in Jasmine 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131838/testing-angularjs-promises-in-jasmine-2-0))

However, this resolves *all* promises, which became an issue for my testing because I had promises which I didn't want to resolve yet.  This was partially due to some ugly hacks to get around an issue with a legacy program which were moving to remove entirely.

another tool which looked quite...promising (pun not intended, honest!) was Mock-promises: http://pivotallabs.com/testing-javascript-promises/

I haven't gotten to use the tool yet unfortunately, but it looks like a good one to play with.