# How do I make sure that a promise is resolved before proceeding to the next lines?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

Say I have the following:

```
var myFuncResult = null;                
browser.executeScript( "return myFunc();").then( function(i){
    myFuncResult = i;
    // console.log([ "myFunc is: ", i]); this is fine
});
console.log([ "myFunc is: ", myFuncResult]);
//do something about myFunctResult
myFuncResult.doSomethingElse();
```

Now the outer console.log is logging null because it has executed before the promise got resolved. How do I prevent that? How do I make sure that the function I provided executes first before console.log? I need my myFuncResult to be initialized before proceeding to the remaining lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want, and this is by design.  The promises will run asynchronously and so the `console.log` statement will always run before your promise gets resolved.  The proper way to make the `console.log` statement run after the promise is resolved is to add another `then` clause, something like this:

```
var myFuncResult = null;                
browser.executeScript( "return myFunc();").then( function(i){
    myFuncResult = i;
    // console.log([ "myFunc is: ", i]); this is fine
}).then(function() {
    console.log([ "myFunc is: ", myFuncResult]);
});
```

You do need to be careful to handle error conditions since the first argument of a `then` clause is not called if a promise is rejected.

Yes, this can lead to spaghetti promises, but it is (slightly) better than callback hell.  Enjoy javascripting!

Comment: Console log doesn't matter to me, what matters is to make sure var myFuncResult is available to the remaining lines of code.

Comment: Then, your remaining lines of code must be placed in the same `then` block as the `console.log` statement.

Comment: I need it inside the it() function for my jasmine test cases. Would that be a good practice?

Comment: You are testing asynchronous code so you have to deal with these promises in your tests.

Comment: If you were to use angularjs, you can (in your tests) resolve your promises synchronously.  But this is a special feature of angular and not anything generalizable for jasmine outside of angular.  For more information, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311118/angular-promise-not-resolving-in-jasmine/20311552#20311552

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using callbacks by doing this inside an async function, for example:

```js
async function main() {
    const myFuncResult = await browser.executeScript("return myFunc();");
    console.log([ "myFunc is: ", myFuncResult ]);
    myFuncResult.doSomethingElse();
}

main();
```

This is currently supported in all major browsers (not IE, but IE is no longer supported). [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/async-functions)